# Crawl distributed file system error: The object was not found

Tags: 2013, search, crawling

SharePoint 2013 Standard server.

We have a a distributed file system (DFS) which I want to crawl.

I use a UNC path like:

```
\\machine1234\Departments\HR
```

The account that runs the crawler can access it. I tested by logging in with that account and pasting the above path into explorer.

I run the a full crawl and get the following error message:

> The object was not found

I run with and without proxy, same difference. Any ideas?

Comment: Is the target server Windows Server 2012 or Windows Server 2012 R2?

Comment: Both DFS and SharePoint run on Windows 2008 R2

Answer (score 0):

It turned out the crawling account needs read and write access

Comment: You can add some more brief description to your answer.